# Swift/Combine- Assign a filtered object to a property on a class

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios11, combine

I have a list of objects.

```
let arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

It lives in a repository.

```
class ArrayRepository: ObservableObject { 
     @Published let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

I have a class with a property that needs it assigned at initialization.

```
class MyClass: ObservableObject { 
    var id: String = ""
    var myProperty: Int? 
}
```

My class is created through an asynchronous process that is itself a repository.

```
class myClassRepository { 
   
    func buildClass -> MyClass { 
        myClassInstance = MyClass()
        self.arrayRepository.$arr.map { arr in 
            arr.filter{ $0 == someOther.Value }
        }.assign(to: \.myProperty, on: myClassInstance).store(in: &subscriptions)
       return myClassInstance
    }
}
```

The problem is my pattern returns an array of elements that I cant make conform to to the singular property on the class? Whats the best way to get it out?

The error I get is essentially

```
Declared closure result '[Int]' is incompatible with contextual type 'Int??'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a limitation of Swift's type system, you cannot currently `assign` to an `Optional` property with a non-`Optional` value. You can, however, create your own version of `assign` that does:

```swift
func assign<Root: AnyObject>(to path: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Root, Output?>, on root: Root) -> AnyCancellable {
    sink { [weak root] in root?[keyPath: path] = $0 }
}
```

This implementation also has the bonus of preventing a reference cycle.

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks for the tip!